# how to avoid CORS policy error in angular PUT method

Tags: javascript, angular, cors

I am trying to use PUT method in Angular,

app.component.ts:

```
this.http.put( this.updateurl+ this.userid, JSON.stringify(user.value))
.subscribe(response =>{
  console.log(response);
});
```

when I do this I get error like:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http:// ***********' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been
> blocked by CORS policy: Method PUT is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods in preflight
> response.

How can I solve this?

Comment: what is your server-side technology? cors policy can be added on the server-side, not in the angular side.

Comment: you should enable cors(cross origin resource sharing) in your server side. You can enable it for specific urls and all urls.

Comment: please read [this](https://sanderstechnology.net/2014/getting-to-know-cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors/13423/#.Xi_bZmgzbQo)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20035101/5468463

Answer (score 0):

```
No ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ header is present on the requested resource.
```

This is because of the **Same Origin Policy** – it says that every AJAX request must match the exact **host**, **protocol**, and **port** of your site.

How to fix it:

Simply just provide access to all the **host**, **protocol**, and **port** by using *.

Modify the server to add the header  **Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ***  to enable cross-origin requests from anywhere (or specify a domain instead of *). 
This should solve your problem.

In you projects web.xml add the following filter

```
<filter>
   <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
   <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>        
        <param-value>*</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
        <param-value>GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD</param-value>
    </init-param>  
</filter>
```

Now for limiting the access to only specific  **host**, **protocol**, or **port** you can use the following param-value

```
<filter>
   <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
   <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>        
        <!-- <param-value>*</param-value> -->
        <param-value>http://localhost:4000,https://myapp.com</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
        <param-value>GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD</param-value>
    </init-param>  
</filter>
```

Now here is this case only the requests from the following urls will be allowed while other will throw a CORS error even if they have a slight change in host, protocol, or port

http://localhost:4000 and https://myapp.com

FYI in above

- http , https --> protocols
- localhost , myapp -> hosts
- 4000 --> port